# Clear and Restart setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, setinterval, clearinterval

In my `setInterval` if the div contains `4) PLACEHOLDER` it will prepend an image
if the div does not contain those words it will clear the interval let's say the div text is true and is `4) PLACEHOLDER` so the interval is cleared but then the text changes to `5) PLACEHOLDER` How can I restart the Interval to check the if statement again?

```
var interval = 500;
var timer = window.setInterval(function() {

   if(jQuery("div.text-split-original").text().trim().indexOf('4) PLACEHOLDER') != -1) {
         $('.scar__label').prepend('<img src="smiley.gif" />');
         clearInterval(timer);
   }

}, interval);
```

I could use an else statement to remove the image instead of clearInterval but when I do this the image gets added over and over again so If there is a solution to add the image only once but have the interval keep playing that would be my best bet:

```
var interval = 500;
var timer = window.setInterval(function() {

   if(jQuery("div.text-split-original").text().trim().indexOf('4) PLACEHOLDER') != -1) 
{
  $('.scar__label').append('<img src="smiley.gif" />');


} 
  else
    {
    $(".scar__label img:last-child").remove()
    }
}, interval);
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So, is it a true statement that if the text contains `5) PLACEHOLDER` that you want to remove the smilie faces and let the interval continue?

Comment: If i'm understanding your question, you'd have to have a secondary interval that checks to see if the placeholder starts with 5, and if the first interval is cancelled, start it again.

Comment: I would use an else statement instead of clearInterval to remove the image if the text isn't '4) PLACEHOLDER' but without the clearinterval the image gets added over and over again instead of once but yes I wish to remove the image if the text isn't 4) PLACEHOLDER but if the text is 4) PLACEHOLDER i want to add the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
(function($) {
  var interval = 500;
  var $smiley = $('<img src="smiley.gif" class="smiley" />');
  
  window.setInterval(function() {
    //see if the text is 4)
    if ($("div.text-split-original").text().trim().indexOf('4) PLACEHOLDER') > -1) {
      //only add a smiley if one does not exist
      if ($('.scar__label').find('.smiley').length < 1) {
        $('.scar__label').prepend($smiley);
      }
      //see if the text is 5)
    } else if ($("div.text-split-original").text().trim().indexOf('5) PLACEHOLDER') > -1) {
      //delete that smiley!
      $smiley.detach();
    }
  }, interval);
  
  window.setInterval(function(){
    if ($("div.text-split-original").text().trim().slice(0, 2) === '4)') {
      $("div.text-split-original").text('5) PLACEHOLDER');
    } else {
      $("div.text-split-original").text('4) PLACEHOLDER');
    }
  }, 2000);
}(jQuery));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="scar__label"></label>
<div class="text-split-original">4) PLACEHOLDER</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to do anything the image no longer pops up

Comment: @Unicornnn updated with a timer to flip the text to show example.  Are any of the fields that I am caching in that method dynamically added to the page after the timeout starts?

Comment: Yes they are added via json I can stop the image multiplying with if(jQuery("div.text-split-original").text().trim().indexOf('4) PLACEHOLDER') != -1 && $(".scar__label img").length == 0)  but then of course it will do this ever 500m so it looks like the image is flashing

Comment: Alright so I took out the caches for everything but the smiley so if content is added after the interval starts it should still find them.

Comment: Cracked it Thank you!